# ZF INI Config file example for setting up Logger

Tags: php, zend-framework

Does anyone have an example of the logger configurations setup in their config.ini file?  I'm having some trouble setting up a logger through the config file and would really appreciate it if someone could show an example of how it should work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use XML configs but you should be able to adapt it

```
<resources>
    <log>
        <stream>
            <writerName>Stream</writerName>
            <writerParams>
                <stream><zf:const zf:name="APPLICATION_PATH" />/../data/log/application.log</stream>
                <mode>a</mode>
            </writerParams>
            <filterName>Priority</filterName>
            <filterParams>
                <priority>4</priority>
            </filterParams>
        </stream>
    </log>
</resources>
```

This is literally copied from the example in the manual - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.log

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed that example in the docs.  Sorry for wasting your time Phil, but cheers for helping me out anyway!

Comment: @blacktie24 No apology required. The available resource plugins page is stupidly long and contains quite a few errors. It's easy to miss things